# Custom ESC alias ESC'es

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

Does anyone know whether it is possible to define custom ESCaliasESC'es in Mathematica?
I figured that one could define custom keyboard shortcuts in "/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/KeyEventTranslations.tr" on Linux system, but many are grabbed by the frontend and cannot be redefined and one runs out of sensible possibilities pretty fast.

**Answer** 
The question has been answered [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/defining-symbol-shortcuts-in-the-front-end) 
(thanks @cormullion)

Comment: This might get (better) answers on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: have a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6725/defining-symbol-shortcuts-in-the-front-end) for starters